# Reload parent view on HttpResponse

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to translate a functionality from a web page to an iPhone page.

The page contains an iFrame within it that POSTs a form to my server:

[image]

I am trying to reload the outer-frame. I have control of the `HTTPResponse`, since it is posting the form to my server. For the website, I can reload the outer frame by returning something like:

```
return HttpResponse('
              <html>
                  Loading...
                  <script>window.parent.location.reload(false);</script>
              </html>')
```

How would I do the equivalent of this in an iPhone app, such that the response would 'trigger' the parent view to reload?

Comment: Isn't the iframe-equivalent just a smaller view overlaying the parent view? All you need to do is to remove the smaller view.

Comment: Ok, but how would I 'know' when to remove the parent view. For example, with the javascript response, that is instructing the parent view to reload from the response, but how would I know that in the app (where javascript would be irrelevant?)